# The Fastest Method I've Seen for Sharing Any (LaTex) Image

Tags: discussion, images

I wanted to share how I do it with everyone as it's extremely quick. Please see my answer.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect the purpose of this "question".

Comment: Related: [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764)

Answer (score 12):

I made myself a seperate command-line tool `pdlcrop`. It's form in bash is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdflatex $1 &&
pdfcrop -margin 6 ${1%.tex}.pdf &&
mv ${1%.tex}-crop.pdf ${1%.tex}.pdf &&
convert -density 300 ${1%.tex}.pdf ${1%.tex}.png &&
cp ${1%.tex}.png ~/crop.png
```

This works as follows: (1) run `pdflatex`, (2) crop the result by `pdfcrop` with a decent margin, (3) overwrite the original PDF file by the crop, (4) covert it to PNG in a reasonable resolution, (5) copy this PNG to my home directory under a standard name.

The step (3) is useful since I use TeXworks and this way I see the correct preview. The step (5) comes handy because when you want to upload the image, you know where to find it.

---

I have yet another tool with a short name `twt` (stands for TexWorks Temp):

```
#!/bin/bash

f=`mktemp`
touch $f.tex
texworks $f.tex
```

This creates a new file `<something>.tex` in the temp directory and opens it with TeXworks.

---

In TeXworks, I created a new typesetting tool with program name `pdlcrop` and one argument `$fullname` and this works for me just right, after hitting Ctrl+T, I get a cropped PNG file in my home dir and a good preview in TeXworks.

Comment: +1! I have a very similar script that uses `pdfcrop` and `convert`, then a simple bbutton pressing in `TeXworks` and the image is ready to be uploaded in Stack Exchange

Comment: Why use `pdfcrop`? If you use `\pagestyle{empty}` no header nor footer will be printed. You can then replace the above by `convert -trim -density 300x300 ${1%.tex}.pdf ${1%.tex}.png` or additionally alternatively if you don't want to have a transparent `png` use `-alpha off`.
(And I suggest saving the boilerplate expansions by a variable `file="${1%.tex}"`. :-) )

Comment: This is definitely the best answer because it doesn't use screen shots. Screen shots not only often have a crappy resolution, they more importantly are virtually useless since the advent of subpixel rendering. As if real photos didn't have enough color fringing.

Comment: Very nice. I use a slightly tweaked convert call: `convert -density $((72 * 4)) ${1%.tex} -resize 25% ${1%.tex}.png` slightly smooths the character edges, getting rid of that jagged 'not anti-aliased' look you sometimes get.

Answer (score 8):

Windows Vista and higher comes shipped with a [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) that allows you to copy any part of the screen to the clipboard and then paste it using the updated Stack Exchange image insertion protocol using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>; formerly you could not copy-and-paste.

This is a step up from using <kbd>PrnScr</kbd> that captures the entire screen to the clipboard, which then requires trimming in something like [MS Paint](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/paint), if needed.

Comment: The active window only can be captured with `Alt`+`PrnScr`.

Answer (score 5):

The [Firefox plugin LightShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/) offers a similar functionality with the exception that it uses Prntscr.com for uploading and you can edit online. You can also share in Twitter, Facebook (why I don't know).

[image]

One function I find often useful is to look for similar images on Google (the right top button).

Answer (score 4):

[ShareX Tool](https://code.google.com/p/sharex/)

This tool allows you to quickly capture portions of your screen, automatically uploads the screenshot to `imgur.com`, then automatically copies the `imgur` link to your clipboard. All you need to do is press `CTRL+V` wherever you need it.

Personally, made the hotkeys such that...

- CTRL+SHIFT+Z: Capture of piece of the screen.
- ALT+PRTSC: Capture the current window.

I use this tool constantly. Cheers~

Comment: Before we get too excited about this, does this upload to the Stack Exchange imgur account? Because if it doesn't images will be lost after some time.  See [How do we repair Gonzalo Medina's posts containing images?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1442)

Comment: @AlanMunn As an alternative, you can have the ShareX automatically copy the filepath, the image, the file, etc. How does one upload manually to the Stack Exchange imgur account? It may be possible to configure ShareX to upload to that account automatically.

Comment: Manually you click on the image icon above the text window.

Comment: @AlanMunn So, any URL I put into this website via that button is uploaded to the Stack Exchange Imgur? In that case, I'm already doing it. The workflow is: CTRL+SHIFT+Z, select area of screen I want to share, ENTER, click on that image icon, then CTRL+V. It only takes about five seconds to share my LaTeX headaches with you guys. It's great. :)

Comment: Ok, then I agree it's great. :)  (On my Mac my workflow is pretty much the same: Command+Shift+4, select area, click on image icon and then choose the file.)

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the fastest way would be to use [screenshot app](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-screenshot/) and/or [shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/) that can be accessed from `Dash Home` as shown in screenshot [image]below

Comment: It's not just on Ubuntu, but on any Linux ([Gnome Screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-screenshot) or [Shutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_(software)) on Gnome / GTK, [KSnapshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KSnapshot) on KDE / QT). :)

Comment: @Xavier With _many_ Linux distro's, _various_ front ends and _umpty_ number of ways(terminal/gui's) to access [screenshot apps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Taking_a_Screenshot), `Dash Home` screenshot was one of many newbie's approach with Ubuntu `Unity` version. `Dash`/Unity is not on other Ubuntu derivatives. Feel free to edit and add value with extra info

Comment: I just meant that your two solutions works on any (common) Linux distribution, not just Ubuntu (`Dash Home` screenshot _is_ `Gnome Screenshot`).

Comment: Real men use `scrot` from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, the quickest way I know is to use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> which gives you a target like cursor and selecting the two opposite corners of a rectangle will grab the image within that rectangle.  This will creae a file named

```
Screen shot 2013-07-08 at 6.36.53 PM.png
```

on the Desktop with the current time stamp.

Comment: If you press the spacebar after cmd+shift+4, then you get a little camera that captures the application window of your choice. Sometimes this is better/easier than the rectangle tool.

Comment: If you also hold down the `option` key, it will save the image to the clipboard instead of the desktop. This can be handy.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick snap shot in Ubuntu 13.04 (and perhaps other Linux distros), I just press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and then open up the `png` file with [`kolourpaint`](http://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kolourpaint/), select the desired part of the picture and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.