# How to provide good looking TeX output in StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I realise that this is not directly concerned with TeX and friends but it is about improving my answers to such questions.

I try and provide an MWE in my answers and I want to show their typeset output which is a PDF file. I have seen that I should use `convert file.pdf file.jpg` to produce a JPEG file for inclusion in my answer. However when provided in my answer the result looks small and blurry whereas I have seen many other answers with good looking graphics. How could I do that? (I have used GIMP to trim the JPEG files but this only removed irrelevant space and left the poor quality image as it was).

Comment: I prefer the output from the mupdf-tools for the mupdf PDF viewer: e.g., `mutool draw -w 900 -o output.png input.pdf`

Comment: `convert` has an option `-density`, try e.g. `convert -density 300 file.pdf file.png`.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: No problem using pdftools from AUCTeX/Emacs. I select the region I want to display, C-TAB and save the image as a png file. (the job is made by Imagemagick)

Comment: I use FastStone Image Viewer 7.5 Freeware (Last Update: 2020-03-10)    

An image browser, converter and editor that supports all major graphic formats including etc ... from https://www.faststone.org/ . Allow the capture of rectangular regions of the pdf viewer so you can zoom to show the issue. Very recommend, no ads. Also has simple tools for editing.

Comment: Or [FSCapture 5.3](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=775) (freeware; went shareware from 5.4) for screen capturing that you can then paste into the question dialog.

Comment: I am on windows but I usually just use xpdf and then the windows "snip" tool to highlight a region and paste in, I prefer this to converting the full page display as you can then focus in on the relevant bits. Especially now the site lets you paste in directly from the clipboard so you don't need to save and upload an image

Comment: Definitely use PNG, or another lossless format. Maybe SX will someday allow SVG.

Comment: GhostScipt, ImageMagick (which uses gs) and pdftocairo are all good conversion programs.

Comment: I think this belongs in the meta, dunno if OPs can move it there. As for the question: I just use screen captures

Comment: Screen captures in PNG format and enough zoom in the PDF viewer will be enough in most cases. If you want capture a big area that does not fit in the screen with enough zoom, then the solution is a PDF to PNG conversion but taking care of the final resolutions, i.e.,  of the pixels per inch in the  web page (not in the source image).

Comment: I'm on a Linux system, and I use the manual equivalent of the recipe given here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3675  More possibilities are given in answers to this question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5954

Comment: Thanks to everybody who provided a comment. There seem to be several approaches and it will take me a little while to try them all out. At the moment `convert -density 300 F.pdf F.jpg` followed (or preceeded) by a crop looks OK.

Comment: @PeterWilson  is it possible to show a real world example to show the problem and the comparison which is better -- I am also interested in improving my answers

Comment: For output containing text avoid using JPEG, that one was made for photo-compression and tends to have bad artifacts.

Comment: @davislor You *can* embed SVG, using the `<img src="..."/>. Alas, SVG cannot be uploaded directly (imgur). You need another SVG hosting service or web server to install the SVG file.

Comment: This is my script: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415278/87678 (although I've improved it a bit since that answer).

Comment: Like @Fran has said, I take a screenshot of the relevant part of the pdf and the result is ok

Comment: Where exactly is this `convert` utility located? I'm on macOS Catalina with a fully updated TeX Live 2020 and `which convert` turns up nothing. `locate convert` shows many things, but nothing obvious. For output uploads I've been using the Mac's built-in `screenshot` utility and it's worked fine for me, but it can't do the animations I sometimes see in answers and I'd like to be able to do that.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I'm on a Linux OS where `convert` is part of the distribution.

Answer (score 7):

SX allows displaying embedded SVG, but does not provide an SVG upload facility itself. Thus, the SVG needs to be installed on a long-living, personal web page or third-party hosting service.

I chose [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) and created a minimal project page from a GitHub repository according to the given instructions. SVG files, later committed to this repository, are readily accessible by their URL. Another option could be https://svgshare.com, that allows SVG uploads without registration, but I am unsure about its reliability.

To display an SVG on SX, embed the SVG URL in an `img` tag:

```
<img src="https://agrahn.github.io/mysvgs/svg/integral.svg" width="300"/>
```

[image]

A useful tag attribute is `width`, without which the image is scaled to text width.

The SVG was produced with

```bash
latex example
dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 example
```

from input

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\[\int_0^1 2x\,\mathrm{d}x=1\]
\end{document}
```

The chosen `dvisvgm` options ensure accurate cropping to the content, embedding the needed font glyphs in a web-browser compliant format, as well as  scalability via the `img` tag's `width` attribute.

Comment: This is good to know, but it has disadvantages. Since you can’t upload the SVG, this could someday lead to broken image links in your answer. It’s also possible to inadvertently create a SVG that displays fine on your computer, but breaks for someone else who doesn’t have the font installed. (Or where it *works* for someone with a different version of the font, so they can’t see what the problem is.)

Comment: The font is not an issue, as it is embedded in the SVG. But the problem of broken links indeed remains.

Comment: You properly embedded the font in the SVG, but it’s entirely possible to create a SVG that doesn’t embed all its fonts. And the poster would have no way of noticing the mistake, because it would display properly for them.

Comment: They would very likely be notified via the commenting function.

Comment: Unless the SVG works for most readers, but not all, or only breaks on a different version of the font years later. If the site allowed SVG uploads, it could in theory check the file and accept only ones that embed all their fonts.

Comment: Doesn't most SVG editors allow glyph conversion to paths? That would fix the font problem as well.

Comment: There is no problem at all; the font can be embedded with `--font-format=woff2`, or converted to paths with `--no-fonts` options. Both make the SVG self-sufficient.

Comment: @Davislor All this sounds rather far-fetched. If the poster correctly uses the available tools, as suggested in the answer, the SVG is self-sufficient. Then, the only potential problem that remains is broken links, which can be minimized by using a reliable and longliving hosting service, GitHub, for instance.

Comment: It’s definitely easy to make a correct SVG! It’s possible to make one that breaks, though. If we could upload SVGs, the site could check that they’re correct.

Comment: The possibility of direct SVG upload with automatic compatibility check is of course desirable.

Comment: I cannot see the image on my browser (Chromium). The image link also shows 503 Over Quota.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis : [Works](https://svgshare.com/i/RcF) for me. Maybe svgshare.com was temporarily unavailable. Nevertheless, I edited the answer, using GitHub Pages now.

Comment: Thanks for addressing. I can see both the images now.